# Why does the subview above MDCCardCollectionCell does not appear?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am using the Material Design Cards to create a collection view. The cards in the collection view appears, but when I add a label with text or image to it, they do not appear. What should I do?

I have imported the MaterialComponents.MaterialCards packages and followed the instructions about collection view in https://material.io/develop/ios/components/cards/#typical-use-in-a-collection-view , but it turns out that I could not put anything on the cell. I have also tried using card as a view, and I can put other things above that.

[The screeprint of the storyboard of the view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GTIY.png) 
[The screenprint of the collection view after added a picture on it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2qPx.png)

```
    @IBOutlet weak var TagCollection: UICollectionView!

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        TagCollection.register(MDCCardCollectionCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "TagCell")
        return 5
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "TagCell", for: indexPath) as! MDCCardCollectionCell
        cell.isSelectable = true
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: Can you please share image what you want and what issue you are facing?

Comment: hi, i have edited and add a link of the picture of the issue I have, now the collection view cell is empty, but I have added a imageview over it, thank you very much

Comment: I think you set imageview in storyboard cell and set class as MDCCardCollectionCell, Also register MDCCardCollectionCell class programatically for identifier "TagCell". Here, every time it will use cell registered programatically. And to set image you need to set image in cellForItemAt.

cell.setImage(UIImage(contentsOfFile: "test.png"), for: .normal)